# Search engine to display video results

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

so I'm working on a school project where I have to develop a search engine to display video results on a webpage. Very similar to YouTube.

So I have been checking out nickfrosty's video on YouTube on how to code a search engine, and have been trying it out on a separate HTML and PHP page.

I have been following his codes, but I am facing several errors which I am unsure of. I am very new to PHP and SQL codes. Hope you guys can help me out!

This is an image showing my web page when i try to run the codes. [image: Search Engine Screenshot]

And these are the codes i am using for my PHP.

```
             <?php

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "seetoh88_mp16");
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT videoID, title, description, thumbnail FROM video" );
            $results = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($videoID, $title, $description, $thumbnail);
            $JJ = $_GET['JJ'];

            $terms = explode (" ", $JJ);
            $query = "SELECT videoID, title, description, thumbnail FROM search";


            foreach ($terms as $each){
                //echo $each."<br>"; //(display searched keywords in array)

                $i++;

                if ($i == 1)
                    $query .=  "keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
                else
                    $query .=  "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%'";                    
            }

         echo $query;


                $query = mysqli_query($query);

                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                if ($numrows > 0){

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){


                        $videoID = $row['videoID'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                        $thumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];

                        echo "<h2>$$title</h2>
                        $description<br /><br />";


                    }


                }
                else
                    echo "No results found for \"<b>$JJ</b>\"";


                $mysqli->close();


         ?>
```

Here is a screenshot for my database table.
[image]

Comment: update ---  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

Comment: @CodeLove Hi there, I updated accordingly but there's still errors. The Web Page still isn't displaying the thumbnails accordingly from my database. Thanks for your help!

Comment: update --- $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'seetoh88_mp16');

Comment: @CodeLove Hi CodeLove, I am using the default settings for the SQL, hence i think its not wrong for the line $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "seetoh88_mp16");

Comment: see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @CodeLove Hi, I have been using the $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "seetoh88_mp16"); for other Web Pages that require a connection to database and it has been working fine so far too. Does that mean i'm doing things wrongly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94390/discussion-between-jun-jie-and-codelove).